# Bash function to cd and open in vim a filename

Tags: vim, cd, bash

When I want to edit a file in vim, I often want to cd to the containing dir before I open the file. My normal process for doing this is...

```
cd filepath/that/contains/
vim filename.d
```

But all too often, I end up typing...

```
cd filepath/that/contains/filename.d
{error: not a directory}
```

I'd like to create a function that will replace cd. Below is what I came up with, but it doesn't work.

```
alias cd='vimcd'

function vimcd () {
    if [ -f $1 ]
         then
            cd $(dirname $1) 
            vim $(basename $1)
    else cd $1
    fi
}
```

Comment: You should quote your variables but what about that doesn't work exactly?

Comment: You may also want to use `(` and `)` to define the function instead of `{` and `}` to execute it in a subshell so that you don't change the directory of your current shell when you run it (unless you want that to happen).

Comment: There's no need to use an alias; you can simply name your function `cd` (after employing the `builtin` solution in BroSlow's answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is an old question, but you could just use the vim plugin: [NerdTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree).
This way, you leave `cd` alone, at the cost of enhancing your editor.

Your command would just be: 
`$ vim filepath/that/contains`

If it's a file, then it opens it for editing. If it's a directory, then it opens a directory browser.

Comment: Funny you mention it, because this is the solution I actually ended using.

Answer (score 3):

The `cd` in your function should be the `builtin`, otherwise it just recurses your function.

```
cd () {
    if [ -f "$1" ]; then
      builtin cd "$(dirname "$1")" 
      vim "$(basename "$1")"
    else
      builtin cd "$1" 
    fi
}
```

Comment: This seems to break when a blank string is passed to the cd function.

Comment: @user2766440 Can you provide an example/what you expect to happen?

Comment: Normally, when I type cd and press enter it changes to my default/home directory. For whatever reason, the above function doesn't. I got it to work by adding another if statement... 
`if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
    builtin cd 
else
    builtin cd "$1"
fi`